# Rails/Rspec Stubs: Specifying order & so forth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

I'm comfortable creating basic stubs, but a little confused about how to specify things such as order (and reversing it), etc.

To give a concrete example, here is a line in my controller that I'm trying to test:

```
@courses = Course.order('created_at').reverse
```

In my controller spec, the (obviously failing) stub is:

```
  Course.stub(:all) { [mock_course] }
```

...and the rspec error:

```
  Failure/Error: assigns(:courses).should eq([mock_course])

       expected [#<Course:0x818614e8 @name="Course_1001">]
            got [#<Course id: 2, name: "Second test course", price: #<BigDecimal:1030e73c0,'0.4995E2',18(18)>]
```

Despite being an inaccurate test (not testing ordering), i would have guessed the spec would pass. It doesn't - it's pulling from the database, not the mock. Soo...I guess what I'm asking is, how do I stub Course.order('created_at').reverse ?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assuming that ActiveRecord will call Course.all at some point, which may not be the case.

Try this:

```
Course.stub_chain(:order, :reverse) { [mock_course] }
```

To avoid having to do chained stubbing, you could move the ActiveRecord code into your model, so the controller would have something simpler such as:

```
Course.all_by_newest_first
```